# Can't Set Optional Foreign Key To Null With Independent Association

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have an optional independent association foreign key in the application, here is the simplify version on the db context and entities.

**The Context**

```
public class AppContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Bar>().HasOptional(b => b.Foo);
    }
}
```

**The Entities**

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}
public class Bar
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Foo Foo { get; set; }
}
```

The context and the entities are located in different assembly and I **can't change** the entities because it's a sub repository and will be used by other projects.

**The Problem**

When I want to remove the foreign key by set it to null, it doesn't change.

```
using (var db = new AppContext())
{
    var bar = db.Bars.Find(1);
    bar.Foo = null;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

This works

```
bar.Foo.Bars.Remove(bar);
```

but in my case, it's not a solution, all bars will be loaded into memory and I don't want to have unnecessary database round trip.

Why and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve it by assigning it to unused variable.

```
var bar = db.Bars.Find(1);
var foo = bar.Foo;
bar.Foo = null;
db.SaveChanges();
```

PS: Assigning the null twice or more doesn't work.

```
bar.Foo = null;
bar.Foo = null;
```

Comment: This is the weirdest answer ever - but it worked. Must be a bug?

Comment: How did you even think to try that? Anyway, worked for me too.

Comment: The Foo getter on the proxy must be doing something